# How to Select a grandchild element of a element using xDocument and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this XML markup:

```
<preferences>
  <section name="PREF_SECTION_NAME_1">
    <preference name="PREF_EXAMPLE_1" type="text">
      <default value="false"></default>
    </preference>
    <preference name="PREF_EXAMPLE_2" type="radio">
      <default value="true"></default>
    </preference>
    <preference name="PREF_EXAMPLE_3" type="radio">
       <default value="false"></default>
    </preference>
  </section>
  <section name="PREF_SECTION_NAME_2">
    <preference name="PREF_EXAMPLE_4" type="radio">
      <default value="true"></default>
    </preference>
    <preference name="PREF_EXAMPLE_5" type="radio">
      <default value="false"></default>
    </preference>
    <preference name="PREF_EXAMPLE_6" type="radio">
      <default value="true"></default>
    </preference>
  </section>
</preferences>
```

I want to get the default value for when the Preference attribute name = "PREF_EXAMPLE_2"

I got this:

```
var t = from p in xDocUser.Descendants("preference").Attributes("name").Where(d=>d.Value==preferencename) select p;
```

which gives me the Attributes for preference but not its child.

How can i do this please?

Comment: Well it's actually just giving you the attributes, not the elements at all. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, or why you're using a query expression which is just `from p in (some stuff) select p`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon, thanks for your comment.  I want to get the default value for when the Preference attribute name = "PREF_EXAMPLE_2" from an xDocument. Are you suggesting do not use linq?

Comment: I should add I am loading the xml document into xDocument.  Are you also suggesting I should just stick with xml selectnodes etc? thanks

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting you don't use LINQ - but I'm suggesting you don't use a pointless query expression. Either use a query expression which makes sense (e.g. using a `where` clause) or just use the lambda-based way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, you're asking for the attributes of preference. It sounds like you actually want something like:

```
var defaults = from pref in xDocUser.Descendants("preference")
               where (string) pref.Attribute("name") == preferenceName
               select (bool) pref.Element("default").Attribute("value");
```

That will give you an `IEnumerable<bool>` of the default values for all the matching preferences.

Comment: My intent was to get the child node of Preference where the condition was met.  I know my code was wrong. I have only just discovered xDocument and I am new to linq :) I prefer to learn by example but obviously the way I worded my question in my Google search is wrong. thanks for taking pity on me!

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: If you just want the element, then change the select clause to `select pref.Element("default")`.